# Logitech mouse - Change settings without Logitech Options [HOW]

Tags: windows-10, logitech-mouse, logitech-keyboard, logitech-headset, logitech-unifying-receiver

I recently got a Logitech bluetooth mouse M590. The mouse supports the Logitech Options & Flow software to change/tweak the mouse settings but my **work laptop does not allow installation of Logi Options** (no admin rights either). I also switch it between my work & my personal laptop which has Logi Options. Both laptops have Windows 10.

Is there a way to customize the mouse without having Logi Options installed on that laptop?

Or some hack like, I tweak the settings using Logi Options on my personal laptop and make the same settings work on the work laptop?

I was planning to buy the MX Master mouse through work, but if I cannot tweak the settings then it doesn't make sense.

Edit:
The work laptop is a secure one, so most likely the request for logi options will be rejected or will take too much time to get approved, so I am looking for workarounds

Comment: Why not ask IT if they'll install it? Without it, [or the ability to install anything else to control it] you're stuck. You will have only the very limited MS mouse CP to control it with.

Comment: I have Logi Tech Options here. The tweaks are not plentiful:  just swap the buttons.  Ask your company admin to install LT Options and then go from there.

Comment: 'not plentiful' ? I've never seen the Windows CP, but the one on Mac has a myriad per-app settings, key-commands, scroll-wheel options etc.

Comment: Yes. Middle button has some options. Windows though I have not needed them.  That is why I said, get LT Options installed and then go from there.

Comment: There is no workaround if you can't install anything. You have the basic functionality offered by Microsoft.

Comment: Is something like this possible, I change the settings using logi options on my personal laptop and use those settings anywhere I connect the mouse. Basically save those settings in the mouse itself

Comment: Because if I can only make the windows level changes then there is no sense in buying a good mouse for work laptop

Comment: As already stated; if you cannot install software, you cannot modify the mouse behaviour. Ask IT, or use the MS default controls. There is no third option.

Comment: oh thats sad, anyways thanks

Answer (score 1):

One option to change settings for the mouse without Logitech Options & Flow software is [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm). It does not need admin rights.

You cannot customize the mouse as much as with Logi Options, but since you are looking for an option which can be installed without admin rights, this could help.

EDIT: there's a commenter who asks for more clarity to this answer. While I'm not the OP, this solved my very similar problem. See [this linked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2Bao.png) (I'm not entitled to embed it here) depicting the UI and showing alternative assignments for mouse buttons 4 and 5 (which by default are assigned to back and forward navigation buttons).

You can keep the application somewhere in your home directory and create a shortcut for it in `$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` to start it automatically on login.

The application itself supports a plethora of options, and even multiple layers to switch to alternative sets of assignments easily, but I only used the two shown in my linked screenshot to reassign the buttons.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from @martes 's answer, it'll likely be slim pickings considering it's for Logitech hardware.  This may or may not be useful to you, but another option you can consider is using [AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/).  This depends on what sort of "customization" you're referring to specifically, but with AHK you can map keys (*including* mouse keys) or bind key/input combos to desired outputs or various functions.  Just a word of caution though: while AHK works great with keyboards, it can be a bit hit-or-miss with computer mice, and you may have trouble trying to work with non-standard inputs, e.g., G-Shift key, etc.  Hoewever, AHK has an active Discord community (among other platforms), so you can always check in there if you have any questions or need help with setting up a script (I use a G502 myself).  Lastly, regarding the security issue, please note that AHK itself is **fully portable**, which means you can compile your script into an `.exe` and run it from, e.g., a USB flash drive on any Windows OS workstation, and doesn't require any software installation.

Answer (score -2):

I have the same issue. I began using [X-mouse](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) last week and like the customizability. When I go to my college and login to one of their computers, I'm frustrated because I can't bring my customized Logitech settings with me. My mind remembers but my hand forgets. I end up pushing a lot of wrong buttons. Plus Logitech's software seems to continuously be using a lot of system resources.

When I tried to install the Logitech software on to the school's computers it was a no go. I don't have admin rights.

Therefore [X-mouse](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) come to the rescue with their portable version.
I miss the convenient user interface of logic text big fat software but now that I have a profile built for This Mouse and have worked with the X-mouse I have gotten used to it. Plus, it is more configurable!

But if you still want to stick with Logitech.... Here is a method to get you get around the situation:

In short this is spooofing USB device/dongle to be a different device (another type of mouse) and then using that device to begin it's installed. Through this process you will come to a (specific) point where you can use have elevated permissions.
At that point go ahead and install your Logitech software.

Basically... Just go around it

- [You can gain admin rights of Windows 10 just by plugging in a Razer mouse](https://tipsmake.com/you-can-gain-admin-rights-of-windows-10-just-by-plugging-in-a-razer-mouse.amp)
- [synap5e](https://github.com/synap5e)/[**razor-eop-XIAO**](https://github.com/synap5e/razor-eop-XIAO)

Since most people won't have this specific Mouse, you will have to spoof the USB ID of it.

Here are the instructions for the razor mouse:

Razor mouse procedure:

[image: Razor mouse procedure]

Basically use the exploit to install the software you need. Fake the USB ID of the mouse, unless you have one, use Explorer to get Windows admin rights once you get to that point in the tutorial. I have underlined the highlights in green in my picture.

USB ID:

[image: USB ID]

This is the USB ID:

```
USB_VID = 0x1532
USB_PID = 0x023e
```

Comment: Doing this may get the OP fired as he is using a locked down secure work laptop. Not recommended.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1135283)

Comment: This could have been a very good (and informative) answer if more care had been taken over its presentation when first posted. However,  (a) The OP has a Logitech mouse and not a Razer, and; (b)`I began using Xmas last week` - what does that even mean? Please [edit] and correct.